# How to break an infinite loop in module from main script?

Tags: python, while-loop, multiprocessing

I'm trying to have a `while` loop in my module for a main script Python. Is there a way to do this without using multiprocessing, as I've seen that multiprocessing isn't viable in modules due to Windows not having `fork` support.

So I'm trying to fit the `while` loop inside either the `start_capture` or `measure` function, and then start the `measure` function as process (if needed), so that it would look either something like this:

```
#mainScript.py
from sensorHandler import SensorHandler
sensors = SensorHandler()
sensors.start_capture()
sensors.stop_capture()

#sensorHandler.py
class SensorHandler():
    def __init__ (self):
        self.sensors = []        

    def start_capture(self):
        process = Process(target=measure,args=(self.sensors,))
        process.start()
    
    def stop_capture():
        process.terminate()            

    def measure(sensors):
        while True:
            #do stuff
```

Or like this:

```
#mainScript.py
from sensorHandler import SensorHandler
sensors = SensorHandler()
sensors.start_capture()
sensors.stop_capture()

#sensorHandler.py
class SensorHandler():
    def __init__ (self):
        self.sensors = [] 

    def start_capture(self):
        while something:
            #do stuff

    def stop_capture():
        something = false
```

But the main point is that I want to break the loop from the main script when I want it to stop measuring. Any recommendations or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You said, "... as I've seen that multiprocessing isn't viable in modules due to Windows not having fork support." I don't know what you mean by "isn't viable." It's true that starting a child process under Windows carries more overhead than Linux, for example. But are you creating and terminating processes very frequently? And in your second example method `start_capture` never returns until `something` evaluates to `True`. But how is the statement `sensors.stop_capture()` going to be executed to set `something` to `True` if the previous statement `sensors.start_capture()` does not return?

Comment: Yeah, the `stop_capture` cannot be executed as the program is stuck in the loop. That is why I don't know how to implement this method. I'm just looking for a solution to this problem. As for multiprocessing, I've read on a couple of questions that Windows doesn't have fork support, so it just infinitely starts processes until it's memory is full when there is multiprocessing that is not in the `if __name__ == "main":` statement. So I thought it wasn't an option. Do you think it still can be used somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can still use multiprocessing in Windows. In general, you just need to ensure that within the main script that you are launching any statement at global scope that directly or indirectly executes a statement that creates a child process is wrapped in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. It is also advisable to place in such a block any statement at global scope that is not required for the initialization of any child process.

But you have other issues with *sensorHandler.py*. First, you do not have required arguments named *self* in the methods `stop_capture` and `measure`. Second, `self.sensors` in class `SensorHandler` is a regular `list` instance (and perhaps not well-named). When the child process is created and presumably appends to this list, it is doing so to a copy of the `SensorHandler` instance that resides in the new address space created for the child process. So, as currently coded, there is no way for the main program to retrieve this list. One solution is to use a *managed list*, which is shareable across processes. But be aware that each operation on this list is slower that if you were using a regular list. So I would have the main process create the managed list and use it to instantiate the `SensorHandler` instance as follows:

In your case, *mainScript.py* will look like:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sensorHandler import SensorHandler
    from multiprocessing import Manager

    with Manager() as manager:
        measurements = manager.list()
        sensor_handler = SensorHandler(measurements)
        sensor_handler.start_capture()
        input('Hit enter to stop capturing... ')
        sensor_handler.stop_capture()
        print(measurements)
```

Then I would code *sensorHandler.py* as follows:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

class SensorHandler():
    def __init__ (self, measurements):
        self.measurements = measurements

    def start_capture(self):
        self.process = Process(target=self.measure)
        self.process.start()

    def stop_capture(self):
        self.process.terminate()

    def measure(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.measurements.append(i)
            time.sleep(1)
```

Prints (when terminated after a few seconds):

```None
[0, 1, 2]
```

Note that I have renamed attribute `sensors` to `measurements` since presumably you are appending to this list sensor readings or measurements and not sensors.

Comment: Thank you so much. This code has helped me quite a bit. It doesn't fully solve the issue (as I haven't given my whole code), but it really has helped me move in the right direction. I realised I was missing the `self` in `self.process = Process(target=self.measure)` and `self.process.start()`. And has also helped me realise that even though I call my function from the main script, it's still stuck in my function as it doesn't have anything to continue the main script. So I have implemented the multiprocessing in the main script to directly make `start_capture` into a process. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you possibly tried a break statement to exit the loop? It would go something like this:

```
while True:
    #do stuff
    break
```

This would cause you to leave the loop and continue with the rest of the code.
Alternatively you can use `.exit()` or `sys.exit()`

Comment: I would love to use break, but here I don't know how to implement it, as it's supposed to act as an infinite loop that breaks when the end user gives it a stop sign. And I don't know how to implement this "stop sign", as the loop is running in the module and it needs a stop from the main program.